# Saving/loading an Android layout with previously programmatically added buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, savestate, activity-oncreateview

I have a very simple question about loading layout in main activity. I have a simple layout defined in activity_main.xml which is loaded in MainActivity's OnCreate() using

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main).
```

Then on a button click, I add another view item (button) which shows up correctly.

But when the app is closed and opened again, I need to retain what was added last time when the app closed. How do I do that?

I searched some questions here, but most of them talk about saving values using SharedPreferences or saving state, but it is not clear if the layout can be saved as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yet another... you need to save values then recreate the buttons based on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is saving latest state values by using `SharedPreferences`, because it is a good way to save any simple data for long term.

Saving state via using `saveInstanceState` is a short term solution and if you close your app completely, saved instance will be gone forever.

**Possible solution:**

First, you cannot save a layout as you think, but you can get the layout's `parameters` and other features as `variables`, then you can save these by using `SharedPreferences`.

Secondly, you should check if there is any saved layout states when you **start** the activity. If any, you can use the pre-saved parameters for adding your layout dynamically/programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for answer, so to save for buttons on a linear layout within a linear layout, I would have to save the text, dimensions, location, etc. for each button and then load them. Is there a method that can be called when user terminates the app which can save this information?

Comment: @Bill as I mentioned before, there is no shortcut to do it, you have to do it manually, like my example solution above.